# How to record an animation into a video

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have done the candle animation tutorial [here](http://compiledexperience.com/windows-phone/tutorials/candle) but I would like to save this animation and convert it to a video so I can play,pause, rewind and fast forward. how would I go about achieving this. Can you help me?

here is my code

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var storyboard = new Storyboard
        {
            RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
        };

        var animation = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames();

        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, CandleImage);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("Source"));

        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 60; i++)
        {
            var keyframe = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
            {
                KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50 * i)),
                Value = String.Format("/Images/candle_{0:D2}.jpg", i)
            };

            animation.KeyFrames.Add(keyframe);
        }

        Resources.Add("CandleStoryboard", storyboard);

        storyboard.Begin();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do everything like that with the Storyboard. See methods like Pause() and Resume() and the SpeedRatio property.

Comment: Great thanks, but would I be able to save the storyboard as a video and upload or share with other users?

Comment: You're probably going to need [Screen recording software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_screencasting_software) and just record the screen. I don't believe there's a way to programmatically convert the storyboard to a video file, though you could play the file and record with another api.